# Reading an array from a yaml file in GoLang

Tags: go

I am trying to read a yaml file that has an array of objects

```
package config

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
)

type DocumentationInfo struct {
    docs []Document `yaml:"document"`
}

type Document struct {
    title    string `yaml:"title"`
    fileName string `yaml:"filename"`
}

func (c *DocumentationInfo) Init() map[string]Document {
    _, b, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
    basepath := filepath.Dir(b)

    yamlFile, err := os.ReadFile(basepath + "/documentation.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, c.docs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    docInfo := make(map[string]Document)

    for _, doc := range c.docs {
        docInfo[doc.fileName] = doc
    }

    return docInfo
}
func NewDocumentConfig() *DocumentationInfo {
    return &DocumentationInfo{}
}
```

yaml file

```
DocumentationInfo:
  document:
    - {fileName: "foo.md", title: "I am an foo title"}
    - {fileName: "test.md", title: "I am an test title"}
    - {fileName: "bar.md", title: "I am an bar title"}
    - {fileName: "nice.md", title: "I am an nice title"}
```

error

```
2023/06/27 13:44:44 Unmarshal: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!map into []config.Document
```

I am not sure if the issue is the yaml file syntax because it is similar to json, however cross referencing documentation it looks correct.

Any advice would be appreciated...

Comment: why not use viper??

Comment: @VishwaRatna did not know about it until now ;)

Comment: You can use online tool suchs as https://zhwt.github.io/yaml-to-go/ that generate your struct: `type AutoGenerated struct {
 DocumentationInfo struct {
  Document []struct {
   FileName string `yaml:"fileName"`
   Title    string `yaml:"title"`
  } `yaml:"document"`
 } `yaml:"DocumentationInfo"`
}`

Comment: Regardless of the data encoding, you must always export the field names in order for another package to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the outermost container as a map with a `document` key containing an array of `Document`s:

```
type DocumentationInfo struct {
  docs []Document `yaml:"document"`
}
```

But that is not the structure of your input data, which looks like this:

```
DocumentationInfo:
  document:
    - {fileName: "foo.md", title: "I am an foo title"}
    - {fileName: "test.md", title: "I am an test title"}
    - {fileName: "bar.md", title: "I am an bar title"}
    - {fileName: "nice.md", title: "I am an nice title"}
```

The outer element is a map that contains a `DocumentationInfo` key (and the value of *that* key is your map with the `document` key). You would need to redefine your types like this (I've turned this into `package main` so I can run it locally for testing):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type DocumentationInfoFile struct {
    DocumentationInfo DocumentationInfo `yaml:"DocumentationInfo"`
}

type DocumentationInfo struct {
    Docs []Document `yaml:"document"`
}

type Document struct {
    Title    string `yaml:"title"`
    FileName string `yaml:"fileName"`
}

func (docinfo *DocumentationInfoFile) Init() map[string]Document {
    _, b, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
    basepath := filepath.Dir(b)

    yamlFile, err := os.ReadFile(basepath + "/documentation.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, docinfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    docmap := make(map[string]Document)
    for _, doc := range docinfo.DocumentationInfo.Docs {
        docmap[doc.FileName] = doc
    }

    return docmap

}
func NewDocumentConfig() *DocumentationInfoFile {
    return &DocumentationInfoFile{}
}

func main() {
    d := NewDocumentConfig()
    docmap := d.Init()
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", docmap)
}
```

Running the above code produces:

```
map[bar.md:{Title:I am an bar title FileName:bar.md} foo.md:{Title:I am an foo title FileName:foo.md} nice.md:{Title:I am an nice title FileName:nice.md} test.md:{Title:I am an test title FileName:test.md}]
```